# Работа с файловой сиcтемой

Tags: java

```
    import java.io.File;

    public class FileLab_LookFor 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            File file = new File("d:/tmp");
            print(file);
        }

        public static void print(File root)
        {
            if (root.isFile())
            {
                System.out.println(root);
            }
            else
            {
                File[] fileArray = root.listFiles();
                for (File file : fileArray)
                {
                    print(file);
                }
            }        
        }
    }
```

Программа должна собирать только имена файлов, которые представляют собой большие (File.length() > 1024*1024) картинки (имя файла заканчивается (String.endsWith(String)) на ".jpg"/".png"/".bmp"/".gif".Информацию выводила в массив файлов, а не в консоль.

Comment: Попробовал реализовать через FileFilter, но запутался, подкиньте идею.

Comment: Что тут путаться-то? Просто реализуете единственный простейший метод фильра и передаёте экземпляр фильтра в listFiles.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на интерфейс [java.io.FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html), напишите свою реализацию

Comment: Спасибо попробую